# Differences in ruby block hash outputs

Tags: ruby, file

I have an input hash. The following codes result in different outputs:

1.

```
read_file = File.open("data_file.txt")
read_file.each{|r| print r}
# => {a => b, c => d}
```

2.

```
File.open("data_reader.txt").each {|d| print d}
# => {a => b, c => d}
```

3.

```
File.open("data_reader.txt") {|d| print d.readlines}
# => ["{a => b, c => d}"]
```

4.

```
File.open("data_reader.txt") {|d| print d}
# => #<File: object in mem>
```

I'm looking for reasons why they are different. Particularly, I'm trying to understand why #3 outputs a list, and #4 stored the object in memory.

Comment: `File.open` accepts a block where file object passed as an argument.

Comment: `File.open("").each` - each accepts a block where every line passed as an argument,block executed for every line.

Comment: `File.open("") {|file| print file.readlines}` where `readlines` returns an array of lines

Comment: @Fabio I thought this, but could not explain #3.  `readlines` should execute similarly to `.each`, no?

Comment: no - because `print file.readlines` will be execute once for the whole file, and `readlines` returns array of string, that why you see `[.., ..., ...]`. Where `.each` will execute `print line` for every line in the file.

Comment: Think of it this way: if you borrow (and read) The Fellowship of the Ring from the library, then The Two Towers, and finally The Return of the King, you will have read three books. When you buy (and read) The Lord of the Rings boxed set, you will have read the same content; but the boxed set is not the same thing as three books (for one thing, there's the box); for another, checking out and having your own is different. Yes? `.each` yields a single line in each pass, and you don't have it once `.each` block is finished, unless you save it somewhere. `.readlines` gives you the array for keeps.

Comment: As an aside `File.open(...).each` would be better written as `File.foreach` the reason being is that `File.open` without a block will hold the file in an open state and since you are not capturing it in a variable you will have to wait for GC to get around to closing it; however `File.foreach` will yeild each line to the block and close the file again when the block terminates leaving this file available for future code as needed.